# How do I wait for an async to complete?

Tags: c#, windows, windows-8, winrt-xaml, async-await

I am currently working on a Chat Client(Windows Store apps - C#) and I'm currently stuck at the registration part. Before I send the relevant data like username, password, email etc. to the server to make a new user, I call the function "CheckSignUp(...)" which checks first if the username already exists. It first sends the keyword /F011/ and then the username, then I should the receive the keyword OK or NOK(username already exists). Here's the code:

```
public async Task<string> CheckSignUp(string username)
    {
        writer.WriteString("/F011/" + "\n");
        writer.WriteString(username + "\n");
        await writer.StoreAsync();

        reader.InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial;
        string result = reader.ReadString(await reader.LoadAsync(3));
        return result;
    }
```

This function is called when I press the "Sign Up" button. The problem is that I get the error  only after the 2nd time I've pressed the "Sign Up" button. Here's the relevant code for the Button_click event:

```
private async void bnSignUp_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
           ...

            string ValidUser = await App.ChatConnection.CheckSignUp(tbUserName.Text);
            if (ValidUser == "NOK")
            {
                FailText.Children.Add(new InfoTextBox("Error! Username already exists."));
                tbUserName.Text = "";
            }
            ....
    }
```

The creation of the `reader` and `writer` objects occurs when connection to the server is made:

```
socket = new StreamSocket(); 
HostName hostname = new HostName(host); 
await socket.ConnectAsync(hostname, port); 
writer = new DataWriter(socket.OutputStream); 
reader = new DataReader(socket.InputStream);
```

EDIT: I also have the same problem when I try to log in(the Login() function works similar like the CheckSignUp one):

```
public async Task<string> Login(string username, string password)
    {
        writer.WriteString("/F050/" + "\n");
        writer.WriteString(GetHash(password) + "\n");
        writer.WriteString("\n");
        writer.WriteString(username + "\n");
        await writer.StoreAsync();

        reader.InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial;
        return reader.ReadString(await reader.LoadAsync(3));
    }
```

Comment: You don't "wait" (or at least, you shouldn't). You "await" - like you already are.

Comment: So how I do solve my problem then?

Comment: Please provide more details about `reader` and `writer` objects. How and where are those created?

Comment: I've created them right after Connection to the server:
    socket = new StreamSocket();
    HostName hostname = new HostName(host);
    await socket.ConnectAsync(hostname, port);

    writer = new DataWriter(socket.OutputStream);
    reader = new DataReader(socket.InputStream);

Comment: Welcome to the world of asynchronous programming. You need to create a task which sends the information to the server and then have the results handled on the "then" part of the task (separate the request from the response). You're not allowed to wait/await on the GUI thread.

Comment: I've seperated the request and response, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend that you first do your best to *not* use TCP/IP. Use WebAPI, SignalR, etc.

If you do ***need*** to use TCP/IP, then you'll need to implement [message framing](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/message-framing.html), as I describe on my blog.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to flush the writer so that your data is actually sent over socket and not buffered.

```
public async Task<string> CheckSignUp(string username)
{
    writer.WriteString("/F011/" + "\n");
    writer.WriteString(username + "\n");
    await writer.StoreAsync();

    await writer.FlushAsync();

    // ..rest of code...
}
```

Comment: And works after 2 attempts? Try to flush on the server as well.

Comment: Yes it's the same. It only works after the 2nd attempt.